# strpos selects everything with 1

Tags: php

I have a data string like

```
$amenities = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
```

these are user selected values from 21 chkbox with these values $amenities will not be fixed

sometimes it will be like

```
  $amenities = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
```

and sometimes

```
  $amenities = 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
```

or sometimes

```
$amenities = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
```

means dynamic field

i am doing something like

```
$amenities = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
     if (strpos($amenities,'1') !== false){?>
 <li class="available_amen"> Smooking allowed</li>
  <?php }else{?>
    <li class="not_amen"> Smooking allowed</li>

     <?php }?>
```

the problem is '1' is actually no there but in 10, 11, 12, 13 "1" is present and strpos detect one is present and run the if else statement

can any one tell me the solution ?
how to solve this issue ?

Comment: `explode()` & `in_array()`.

Comment: @Wrikken post this as answer

Comment: Use array to store these values from the start. Then check `$amenities[0]` for whether or not value is there.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just go about and search for `1` in such a string, there are so many 1s there as you noticed yourself. Make it a little more organized search.

```
$search=1;
$values=explode(",",$amenities);

if(array_search($search,$values)!==FALSE)
{
   // 1 is there
}
```

Comment: Why `array_search` when `in_array` is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
$amenities = '7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19';
```

Then do:

```
$amenities = explode(',', $amenities);

if (in_array(1, $amenities)) { ?>
  <li class="available_amen"> Smooking allowed</li>
<?php } else { ?>
  <li class="not_amen"> Smooking allowed</li>
<?php }
```

See also [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).